# How to backup browser state after Watir automation

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

```
Summary of tools:
 watir-webdriver 1.8.17
 Mac OS X 10.7.3
 Chrome 18.0.1025.151
```

I'm currently using Watir WebDriver to automate Chrome sessions across a number of websites. I need to backup the state of the web browser (cookies, cache, etc.) at certain points throughout the session. Originally, I figured I could do this with Ruby's file IO library by copying `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default` at the necessary points. However, it does not appear that Chrome sessions created with Watir WebDriver store the needed information in this default location. How can I locate this data to back it up? Is this information stored elsewhere? Is there something other than Watir that would make this easier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally have a solution!

It appears that watir-webdriver stores the browser state/user data in random path. By default this can be found here (where XXXXXX is the random identifier):

`/private/var/folders/2v/vkd2v3vs5njf69m59nqzc16m0000gn/T/.com.google.Chrome.XXXXXX/Default/`

Instead of relying on this default and randomized path, you can specify a precise location for the user data using the following flag:

`Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--user-data-dir=/path/to/user/data]`

Then the cache, cookies, etc. can be backed up, deleted, etc. using Ruby's standard library. Hopefully this helps someone else.

**Edit:** If you are unable to find where watir-webdriver is storing your user data by default, find Chrome's process id by running watir-webdriver and `top`. Once you have the pid, type `lsof -p <pid>` into terminal to find the path to the user data.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing I like to do is serialize(save) the Watir::Browser object into a file using YAML, like so:

```
require "yaml"
 File.open("browserObj.yaml", 'w').write YAML::dump(@browser)
```

This **browserObj.yaml** file will then contain all sorts of internal details in easily readable/parseable text, including PID of whichever browser, path to temp profile, etc. Eg.

```
profile_dir: /tmp/webdriver-rb-profilecopy20121201-1981-9o9t9a
```